# Create Com Add in is shown in Inactive Application Add-ins in Outlook 365

Tags: outlook, office365, comaddin

I created a Com Add in using visual studio 2010 Shard Add-in project template. When i build the project, the registry entry is written. When i open outlook 365 it shows the Add in Inactive Add in section. How can i get it to work?

I followed the below step by step walk through at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/office-com-add-in-using-visual-c

Below is the error i see in outlook

[image]

Comment: You really need to run your addin under the debugger to see what that runtime error is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. It seemed that the add in was created as a 32 bit application. I was running 64 bit outlook 365. I downloaded the 32 bit version of outlook 365 and the add in worked.